# Visual studio Windows Forms project installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, installation

Visual Studio 2010 windows project.

Debug folder:   2 dll files, 1 SQLite database.

If I create a windows installer and mail it to my friend should I be worried as to whether the intaller is inclusive of the database or even I have to mail the database file seperately so it should be saved somewhere in the client machine.

If it has to be saved, then it is the concern of data 
source in connection string in the code part.

Comment: Your question (should I include a database file that my program requires, in my installer  and how can I write my connection string so my program can find it on the client ) is too general

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite.Interop.dll is not an assembly but a native DLL. If you decompile System.Data.SQLite you will find the class "UnsafeNativeMethods.cs" which use p/invoke. Exemple with dotpeek :

```
  [DllImport("SQLite.Interop.094.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr sqlite3_malloc(int n);
```

Unmanaged DLL can't be add to your project. So you need to do it by yourself.

1. On your visual studio project add an existing item.
2. Add the native DLL (SQLite.Interop.dll) using shortchut.
3. In VS choose Content for Generation Action and CopyToOutputFolder (if newer or always).
4. In your setup project check you have the main output.

It should work.

My first answer on stack overflow :-)

Comment: Confrtulations!!  : ) My only task is to send my friend the setup file. So can I create a set up file  with **Mydatabase.mdf**  and **System.Data.SQLite** dll in debug folder. Later if i need to check it for myelf in some other machine what I need to do.

Comment: Do you have create a setup project ?

Comment: "I tried to crete setup file in both debug and release mode, the build did not succeed." So how have you try to create your setup ?